# how can i get the import path of a react element in bun?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bun

I'm trying to hydrate a react SSR element but I need to know it's import path so I can add it to the rendered HTML and then dynamically import it in my client-side code.

`example.tsx`:

```
import Home from '../pages/Home'

const element = <Home name="joe" />

// i need something like this:
const path = element.meta.path
```

How do I get the import path of `element`?

I'm looking for a result like `../pages/Home.tsx`

Comment: How did you come to this solution? Maybe instead of asking how to do this, we should evaluate why you need to do it in the first place.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski like i said its for SSR. i pass the component path to my HTML, then hydrate it afterwards using client-side code. i need a dynamic import that uses the component path.